# Body falling off a smooth hemisphere - simple but I'm missing something. What is it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy-conservation, free-body-diagram

So here's the question that I'm stuck on.

> A particle slides from the top of a smooth hemispherical surface of radius $R$ which is fixed on a horizontal surface. If it separates from the hemisphere at a height $h$ from the horizontal surface the speed of the particle when it leaves the surface is:

I can simply apply Conservation of Mechanical Energy(or Work-Energy Theorem, if you think like that) and get the first option as my answer =$ \sqrt{2g(R-h)}$

But, if I make a free body diagram at any arbitrary angle from the vertical I make the following equation-   $mg\cos(x) - N= (mv^2)/R$

The particle leaves the surface when $N=0$
This gives us $v=\sqrt{Rg\cos(x)}$ and as $R\cos(x) =h\Rightarrow v=\sqrt{gh}$, which isn't an option.

Maybe I'm missing some concepts about circular motion and I can't understand what it is? Please help.

Comment: You haven't given us any diagram to show us how you defined your variables so we can't really tell you what's going on here, suffice to say it sounds like your cosine is incorrect.

Comment: Without Latex this is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, both of them are true! The one with
$$v=\sqrt{2g(R-h)}$$
and $$v=\sqrt{gh}$$
But How? See the leaving condition

$$mg\cos\theta =\frac{mv^2}{R}\Rightarrow \cos \theta =\frac{v^2}{Rg}$$
and from the energy conservation at two points
$$v^2=2g(R-h)$$

$$\Rightarrow \cos\theta =\frac{2(R-h)}{R}$$

If you look at the diagram, You will find from simple geometry that
$$\cos \theta =\frac{h}{R}=\frac{2(R-h)}{R}$$
$$\Rightarrow h=\frac{2R}{3}$$
If you put this into both of the expressions for $v$, You find the same result.
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}Rg}$$